# Further maths Edexcel Core Pure $2$ June $2019$ Question $5(b)$ unsure about negative sign

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

[Further maths Core Pure Edexcel June 2019 Question 5(b)](https://www.physicsandmathstutor.com/pdf-pages/?pdf=https%3A%2F%2Fpmt.physicsandmathstutor.com%2Fdownload%2FMaths%2FA-level%2FPapers%2FEdexcel-Further%2FCore-Pure-2%2FQP%2FJune%25202019%2520QP.pdf):

> $5. $ An engineer is investigating the motion of a sprung diving board at a
> swimming pool.  Let $E$ be the position of the end of the diving board
> when it is at rest in its equilibrium position and when there is no
> diver standing on the diving board.
>
> A diver jumps from the diving board.
>
> The vertical displacement, $h$ cm, of the end of the diving board
> above $E$ is modelled by  the differential equation
>
> $$ 4\frac{d^2 h}{dt^2} + 4\frac{d h}{dt} + 37 h = 0 $$
>
> Where $t$ seconds is the time after the diver jumps.
>
> $(a)$ Find a general solution of the differential equation.
>
> When $t=0$, the end of the diving board is $20\,\mathrm{cm}$ below $E$ and is
> moving upwards with a speed of $55$ $\mathrm{cm}\,s^{–1}$.
>
> $(b)$ Find, according to the model, the maximum vertical displacement
> of the end of the  diving board above $E$.

You can find the mark scheme [here](https://www.physicsandmathstutor.com/pdf-pages/?pdf=https%3A%2F%2Fpmt.physicsandmathstutor.com%2Fdownload%2FMaths%2FA-level%2FPapers%2FEdexcel-Further%2FCore-Pure-2%2FMS%2FJune%25202019%2520MS.pdf).

And a model answer to the question [here](https://www.physicsandmathstutor.com/pdf-pages/?pdf=https%3A%2F%2Fpmt.physicsandmathstutor.com%2Fdownload%2FMaths%2FA-level%2FPapers%2FEdexcel-Further%2FCore-Pure-2%2FMA%2FJune%25202019%2520MA.pdf).

In the model answer to $(b)$, they wrote, "*answer is negative as it is the displacement above $E$ (which is negative)*. Remember: displacement is a **vector.** "

I think this is incorrect because based on the definition of displacement in the question, the displacement of the diving board above $E$ is $(+)16.7\,\mathrm{cm}$, not $-16.7\,\mathrm{cm}$. Am I right or wrong? If wrong, then why?

Comment: Try to embed your links. It looks really ugly without and makes the post harder to read

Comment: @FShrike Fair enough. Thanks

Comment: At a guess, the maximum absolute distance from $E$ is attained when the board is below $E$ which makes the final answer negative. I agree that "maximum vertical displacement *above* $E$" is poor wording and makes it sound like they just want the greatest distance *above* $E$ that is attained

Comment: Under this interpretation, if you solve the differential equation and identify that the greatest absolute value of $h$ occurs when $h<0$, you know the answer has to be negative

Comment: Responding to your first comment: There's poor wording, and then there's wording that is clearly asking for something they didn't intend to ask. How could "maximum vertical displacement above $E$" be interpreted as maximal distance from $E$? Your second comment doesn't hold water. Just because the greatest absolute value of $h$ occurs when $h<0,$ that doesn't mean the answer has to be negative, because they don't ask for the distance, they ask for the displacement above $E.$

Comment: My point is that they are likely viewing $-16.7$ as a displacement from ("above") $E$

Comment: I agree with you though. A level exam boards have a lot to answer for; they have a penchant for asking one thing and expecting another and for making the student second-guess and triple-guess themselves

Comment: Ok, wait. So did they mean to phrase it like this: "Find the displacement above $E$ of the point where the board has a maximum distance from $E$?" Then $-16$ does make sense. Anyway yeah, I would have answered $16.7cm.$ And this is what it says in the mark scheme, so...

Comment: I think so. The maths, physics and chemistry exam boards have a real difficulty clearly distinguishing between "maximum, greater/higher" and "maximum, greater/higher *in absolute value*". E.g. the mathematical maximum of $[-3,1]$ is just $1$, but in many instances we would be expected to go for $-3$. Vexing

Comment: @FShrike thanks, that answers the question. But it doesn't answer for the mathematical crimes of the exam boards haha.